# Partially highlighting uitableviewcell - iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom uitableviewcell, which behaves different when run on iOS 8. It works completely fine on iOS 7. The cell get partially highlighted on selection. Here is a screenshot below for running on iOS 8:

[image: Partial cell selection]

The code that handles iOS 7 & 8 cases are as below:

```
 #pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
 }

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   } else {
      return [self heightForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   }
}
```

Comment: the problem might not be the height, what is your cellForRow?, how is your custom cell ?

Comment: Are you using SDK 7 or SDK 8 to build the project? Is the screenshot from a real device or the simulator?

Comment: How do you highlight your cell on selection ?